# Remove Django app name from path with custom domain Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have a Django app running on Heroku and just got a custom domain set up for it.  I would like to be able to remove the app name from the path (www.customdomain.com/app-name).  I have tried working with the project's urls.py to give it an empty string regex and map that to my App's urls.py but that will only work with the index page.  Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Github: https://github.com/Schins02/stats

Site: http://www.texasrangersstats.com/rangerstats/

(Would like to remove app name rangerstats from path)

EDIT: Whoops, this was a lot easier than I thought, just import the views from the app into the project's urls.py and map the routes there.

Comment: You'll need to show some code and some examples of what you want. There's no need to use an app name in the URL unless you want to. Also, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with Heroku specifically.

Comment: I have a project called 'stats' with a urls.py that routs urls to the the app living inside the project called 'rangerstats' to handle the requests via this regex  in the project's urls.py : url(r'^rangerstats/', include('rangerstats.urls')).   Github : https://github.com/Schins02/stats  Site: http://www.texasrangersstats.com/rangerstats/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, if you don't want a prefix, don't use one.

Either include your app URLs with no prefix:

```
url('', include('rangerstats.urls')),
```

or copy your app's URLs directly into the main urls.py.